# Special keyword in mysql select statement

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following script:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1  WHERE COLUMN1='$exb';
```

$exb is a PHP variable which is fed from an HTML select list with 3 values:0,1,2. Values 1 and 2 correspond to column1 values. In case of selecting value 0, I want to include all the values of COLUMN1. Is there a way to implement the above without changing the script? In other words is there any keyword to assign to $exb which will oblige the script to select all the rows of table TABLE1 in case the user selects 0 from HTML select list?
Thank you

Comment: Whattttttttttttttt you are asking?

Comment: Don't try to wrap conditionals in your `SQL`, alter your `SQL`-statement accordingly in your PHP based on the input filter

Comment: How you downvote if you do not understand????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear, but I think you are asking is there a special clause you can add to a where clause to return every single row from the database rather than specific criteria matched in a where clause.

You can put in a pretend where clause by saying `col1=col1` which is effectively a bogus (though valid) syntax like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1  WHERE COLUMN1=column1;
```

Though it would have to be without the quotes to select every single row of the table.

Putting the quotes around the variable would be very simple in your php however.

**Having said that, wouldn't it be much easier to simply omit the where clause entirely if the value selected is 0?**

Comment: Why the downvote? The syntax is valid and answers the question as it is written - and I point out the better solution to obtain the same result?

Comment: I gave you my vote as to compensate the downvote which is not understandable to me, also. Some get happy with downvoting. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: +1 for good answer and empathy.. well done

Answer (score 1):

For this you require to build a dynamic query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1";
$exb = isset($_GET['exb']) ? $_GET['exb'] : 0;
$goodParam = array(0,1,2);//array of allowed values
if($exb>0){
    if (in_array($exb, $goodParam)) {
    $query .= " WHERE COLUMN1 = '$exb'"; 
    }
}
echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with MySql query only. You need to use php and ifelse statement where you can check for $exb value before executing query. For example:

```
if($exb == "0")
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1";
else
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1  WHERE COLUMN1='$exb'";
```